# MySQL Joining two queries for sports team

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to display a list of teams with the number of goals they have scored (and order them by greatest to smallest) but am having trouble with joining all the queries together

Table 1: Teams

```
teamid teamname
  1      team1
  2      team2
  3      team3
```

Table 2: Results

```
 id gameid teamid gf
  1    1     1    5
  2    2     1    3
  3    1     2    0
  4    2     2    2
  5    3     3    0
```

What I'm trying to achieve

```
  1. Team1 8
  2. Team2 2
  3. Team3 0
```

**Get list of all teams**

```
SELECT team.teamid, team.teamname
 FROM teams team
```

**Gets sum of goals for 1 team**

```
SELECT COALESCE( SUM( gf ) , 0 ) goalsfor
FROM results
WHERE teamid = 1
```

**Joining of queries**

```
SELECT team.teamid,
       team.teamname,
       COALESCE(res.gf, 0) goalsfor
FROM teams team
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(res.gf), 0) goalsfor
   FROM results res
   GROUP BY teamid) res ON team.teamid = res.teamid
ORDER BY goalsfor DESC
```

Been stuck on joining the queries all day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT teams.teamname, res.goals FROM teams JOIN (
    SELECT COALESCE(SUM(results.gf),0) AS goals, results.teamid AS teamid FROM results
    group by results.teamid) res
ON teams.teamid=res.teamid ORDER BY goals DESC;
```

Comment: So this one works the best however, when there is a team with no data in the results table it doesnt show up, Is there a way to have the team show up but with all the data showing as 0, i know this has something to do with join vs outer join

Comment: Yes, left outer join res.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:

```
SELECT t.id,
    t.name,
    SUM(r.gf) goalsfor
FROM team t
LEFT JOIN
    results r ON t.id = r.teamId
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY goalsfor DESC
```

My result from my dummy table:

```
id name     goalsfor
1  Apple    8
2  Banana   2
3  Carrot   0
```

I don't think you need `COALESCE` if you made your columns have a default of 0 and cannot be null.